# Does memory get freed at the end of a function if you don't use delete?

Tags: c++, memory, new-operator, delete-operator

Say you have a function like:

```
void foo()
{
  char* pt = new char[10];
  //do stuff with pt
}
```

Since the pointer was created locally, will the memory be freed once the function terminates? Or do you really need to use `delete[]` to free the memory?

Comment: The *pointer* was created locally, not the thing it points to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Memory allocated with `new`/`new[]` have *dynamic storage duration.* They are not deallocated until the user explicitly calls `delete`/`delete[]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That cleared things up.

Comment: So unless pt was declared globally or as apart of a class, it wouldn't be accessible past the termination of the function and the memory would still be allocated, correct?

Comment: @user1747719 Correct. You'll have lost any access to the allocated object. That's a memory leak.

Comment: Note that "smart pointers" care about the deletion whenever *they* are deleted. Using them in *automatic storage duration* triggers that.

Answer (score 2):

If you use "new" or "new[]" without using some sort of smart pointer class, the memory will **not** be freed automatically. You'll need to call "delete" or "delete[]" appropriately to free it.

Comment: Wow I did not know `malloc()` was replaced in C++

Comment: @roliu Where have you been learning C++?

Comment: @roliu malloc + free vs. new + delete. They belong together, each other. Never delete some malloc'ed and never free some new'ed memory. malloc never got "replaced".

Comment: Yeah, you **can** still use malloc (and free to free anything allocated with it), but generally you should be using new and delete instead. Using malloc just means you're writing C and compiling it with a C++ compiler.

Comment: @leemes Well `operator new` is more like the `malloc` replacement.

Comment: Yeah, but this is even more confusing. Let's keep it simple ;) (It's still different, but of course more like malloc than "the whole" new)

Comment: @sftrabbit I haven't been learning C++ :). Unless you count the time when I copied someone's C++ code into a web browser compiler to figure out what the bug was. I was going to answer this question and talk about how local variables are allocated on the stack. Then I noticed the word `new` and I remembered that that's not how you make   statically allocated arrays in C.

Answer (score 1):

No - this is a memory leak.  Every `new` should have a corresponding `delete` (and every `new[]` should have a corresponding `delete[]`).

Comment: Good advice, but old fashioned. If you use smart pointers you'll never encounter a `delete`, nor will you need to.

Comment: @MarkRansom: But there is still a corresponding delete for every new, even if you are not directly invoking it in your own code. (I know you know this, but for others reading your comment)

Comment: @MarkRansom - agreed!  however, on our project we've had smart pointers in-place for a long time, and still encounter situations where you need to deal with raw pointers (e.g. working with COTS libraries, etc.)  People still need to learn new/delete in C++ (with a preference to use and understand smart pointers, wherever possible).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you definitely need `delete[]`. It may be in the same function or somewhere else (if in case you choose to return `pt`).

If you use a container, e.g. `vector`, then you don't

```
std::vector< char > pt( 10 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You really need to use `delete[]`.

Comment: Or better, use an actual string object instead of dynamically-allocating arrays of `char`.

Comment: it was just an example